# How can I restrict this PHP code to crawl links that have the same base with the domain given?

Tags: php

I am writing a code is a crawler but I want it to crawl all the links that have the same base. For example if you set a big depth and you have a link in your page that links to your twitter, it will scan twitter and give you results like twitter.com/xxxyyyzzz.

What I want is to restrict the code to crawl only the urls that have the same base. I don't mind if I set the domain again in a new variable.

Filtering the results and showing only the correct links at the end is not the appropriate way. Imagine if you find 1000 links and you just want the 10.

Thank you for the ideas.
(the correct code is in the answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### MODIFIED

Try this on for size

```
function crawl_page($url, $depth = 2) {
    static $seen = array();
    if (isset($seen[$url]) || $depth == 0) {
        return;
    }
    
    $seen[$url] = true;
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    if (!$parts || !@$dom->loadHTMLFile($url)) {
        return;
    }
    
    $anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {
        $href = $anchor->getAttribute('href');
        $path = false;
        if (0 !== strpos($href, 'http') && 0 !== strpos($href, 'javascript:')) {
            $path = '/' . ltrim($href, '/');
            if (extension_loaded('http')) {
                $path = http_build_url($url, array('path' => $path));
            }
            else {
                $href = "{$parts['scheme']}://";
                if (isset($parts['user'])) {
                    $href .= $parts['user'];
                    if (isset($parts['pass'])) {
                        $href .= ":{$parts['pass']}";
                    }
                    $href .= '@';
                }
                $href .= $parts['host'];
                if (isset($parts['port'])) {
                    $href .= ':' . $parts['port'];
                }
                $path = $href . $path;
            }
        }
        else {
            $href_parts = parse_url($href);
            if($href_parts['host'] == $parts['host'] && $href_parts['scheme'] == $parts['scheme']) {
                $path = $href;
            }
        }
        if (!empty($path) && $depth - 1 != 0) {
            crawl_page($path, $depth - 1);
        }
    }
    echo "Crawled: {$url}\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I have tested it but I don't get all the results. In fact I get only a few and then stops.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. In the next step I will try to get the emails from the current link that is crawled.

Comment: on the outside of that statement try adding an `echo "REFUSED TO CRAWL: {$href}<br/>\n";` and see what you get.

Comment: I added it between the lat two `}` of your posted code and it shows me the urls that was previously used to crawl. It contains urls in the format of domain.com/ and urls on outside pages

Comment: I modified the whole thing, try it out

Comment: Tested and working! Please explain to me whether the script works on the "refused to crawl links". And als, is `$path` the variable that I need to preg_match it to find any emails ? And one last thing, why there is a `$depth = number` isn't supposed to get the number from the `crawl_page("http://domain.com", 5);` ?

Comment: The script shouldn't work on the "refused to crawl" links.  for catching e-mails, you'll want to see if `substr($href,0,7) == 'mailto:'`.  The check on the depth is supposed to save time by not calling the function if the depth would fail anyway, but you can get infinite depth (effectively, at least) by specifying `$depth = -1` when you call the function.

Comment: To clear my mind, by having this `$depth = 2` and 
`crawl_page("http://domain.com");` that I tested and working is faster?

Comment: I didn't succeed on getting the emails of the current crawled page. However I was wondering what if the email is not a `mailto` link? At the end can this be done with a code addition on that script or should I write a new function that uses the crawled url to get again the page and find the email? It seems like double time.

Comment: Below `echo "Crawled: {$url}\n";` I used a file_get_content of the current url and a preg match all to get the emails. It is working OK but I do not know if this is the quickest method, like getting/downloading again the same page.

Comment: Near the top of the function you could do something like `$content = @file_get_contents($url);`, make sure that returned something, and then instead of using the `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile` method you could use `@$dom->loadHTML($content);`